# What is the "types first" Flow architecture?

Tags: javascript, flowtype

A [blog post](https://medium.com/flow-type/what-the-flow-team-has-been-up-to-54239c62004f) by the Flow team describes a "re-architecture" of Flow called "types-first". As far as I can tell, the only description is in this quote from the blog post:

> "...it exploits full type annotations at file boundaries to perform better (more parallelizable and less redundant) separate compilation."

Is there more detail about this anywhere? Specifically, I'm wondering what these full annotations are: what are the new restrictions on source code and declaration files?

For example, is this allowed?

```
import { func } from "./other-module";
export const myNumber = func(num1, num2);
```

It's problematic in TypeScript, since the type of `myNumber` is impossible to resolve without knowing the type of `func`. Will the "types-first" re-architecture of Flow require users to write:

```
import { func } from "./other-module";
export const myNumber: number = func(num1, num2);
```

This is just one specific question I have. What I'm looking for is a little bit more information and a link to a document explaining all the known implications of the re-architecture.

Comment: https://medium.com/flow-type/improvements-to-flow-in-2019-c8378e7aa007

Comment: As always with flow - no documentation, no much info besides change log on github...

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Check out [the Flow docs on Declaration Files](https://flow.org/en/docs/declarations/).

Comment: You will have to write the latter, flow will not be automatically infer the type for the former anymore and will complain

Comment: If one of these comments is converted to an answer and expanded a bit, I'd be happy to mark correct.

Comment: Docs https://flow.org/en/docs/lang/types-first/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It sounds really flashy and maybe it is under the hood. But in reality it's quite simple. In your code snippet you're absolutely correct, it pretty much means just that.

> You must have an explicitly defined type before you export

Though not necessarily right before you export. The following works too.

```
const TestComponent = (): React.Node => {};

export default TestComponent;
```

It adds a little more overhead, but the benefits are:

- improvements in performance because flow doesn't need to scan all dependencies before it can give you soundness checks
- More reliable code because flow runs within module boundaries so you don't get flow errors that are caused by deeply nested dependencies.

They've also released a new blog post that goes into this further since types first have now been released officially.
https://medium.com/flow-type/types-first-a-scalable-new-architecture-for-flow-3d8c7ba1d4eb

**UPDATE** The types-first architecture is now [documented](https://flow.org/en/docs/lang/types-first).

Comment: Can I update your answer with a link to https://flow.org/en/docs/lang/types-first/ ? Aleksey L. linked to it in a comment above

Comment: Definitely go for it!

Comment: @MaxHeiber Sorry if this question seems silly but are the improvements in performance in flow itself or in your application code? I've started reading the flow documentation and it's not clear to me from reading it so far. (I'm guessing it's performance improvements in flow)

Comment: Performance is how fast flow can analyse your code and provide you errors. Flow has zero impact on the performance of your application as it's not runnable code. All flow code must be stripped before it's runnable on node or the browser because it's not "real" JS

Comment: @Brianzchen thanks for the clarification, very much appreciated. I understand the reason for introducing the update. (imho) This update does seem to introduce a lot of extra overhead (updating your code base), especially if your working on a large project. Thanks again for the reply. :)

Comment: fwiw, documenting the public API of a module seems to me to be helpful for human code readers as well as for tools, so it sounds like this "types first" thing has potential to improve human performance as well as machine performance.