# signature-verification-failure in Interface on Arrow function in Flow

Tags: javascript, flowtype, arrow-functions

I recently updated a project using Flow to version 0.138.0.
After the update, it's the first time I'm stumbling upon similar errors like this:

> Cannot build a typed interface for this module. You should annotate the exports of this module with types. Missing type
> annotation at property `_dispatchUpdate`: [signature-verification-failure]

Our project consists of many classes and some of them will look like this

```
export class SomeActions {
  _interval: IntervalID;
  _isPolling: boolean;

  _dispatchUpdate = (downloadItems: DownloadItems[]): void => {
     AppDispatcher.dispatch({
       actionType: CONSTANT.CONSTANT,
       downloadItems,
     })
  }
} 

export default new SomeActions();
```

In order to solve the error in question, I began implementing an interface like the following

```
interface SomeActionsT {
  _interval: IntervalID;
  _ isPolling: boolean;
  
  _dispatchUpdate: (DownloadItems[]): void;
}

export class SomeActions implements SomeActionsT {
  _interval: IntervalID;
  _isPolling: boolean;

  _dispatchUpdate = (downloadItems: DownloadItems[]): void => {
     AppDispatcher.dispatch({
       actionType: CONSTANT.CONSTANT,
       downloadItems,
     })
  }
} 

export default new SomeActions();
```

But the flow error still exists. If I refactor the _dispatchUpdate to being a normal function, it will not complain anymore. But that's silly. How can I go about making flow recognize the arrow function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you're getting these errors probably because you updated from an old version that didn't have types-first on by default. Explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62192653/13243085).

To solve your issue you can type your class like so

```
export class SomeActions {
  _interval: IntervalID;

  _isPolling: boolean;

  _dispatchUpdate: DownloadItems[] => void = (downloadItems) => {
    AppDispatcher.dispatch({
      actionType: CONSTANT.CONSTANT,
      downloadItems,
    });
  }
}

export default (new SomeActions(): SomeActions);
```

Because you're exporting `new Class` you have to declare the type of that also explicitly, otherwise just `export default SomeActions;` is sufficient.

Comment: Cheers, this worked. I found the one you were referring to but couldn't make any sense out of the parameter and return type. This is great. Thanks so much!