# How to correctly type render props in Flow?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flowtype

I can't figure out how to correctly type a Wrapper and Counter component when using render props. I've tried the following but it just leads to more errors:

App.js

```
// @flow
const App = (): React.Node => {

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Wrapper render={(count, increment) => {
        return <Counter1 count={count} increment={increment}/>
      }}/>

      <Wrapper render={(count, increment) => {
        return <Counter2 count={count} increment={increment} />
      }}/>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Wrapper.js

```
// @flow
import * as React from 'react';

type WrapperProps<T> = {
  render: T => React.Node
};

export const Wrapper = <T>({render}): Props<T> => {
  const [count, setCount] = React.useState<number>(0);

  const increment = (prevCount: number) => setCount(count + 1);

  return (
    <div>
      {render(count, increment)}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Counter1.js

```
// @flow
import * as React from 'react';

export const Counter1: React.Node = ({ count, increment }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <div>Counter 1: {count}</div>
      <button onClick={increment}>Increment</button>
    </>
  );
};
```

Counter2.js

```
// @flow
import * as React from 'react';

export const Counter2 = ({ count, increment }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <div>Counter 2: {count}</div>
      <button onClick={increment}>Increment</button>
    </>
  );
};
```

I currently have 14 errors and I'm really lost. I can't figure out how to type Wrapper props and counter props. Here are some of the errors:

```
Error ┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈ src/App.js:35:17

Cannot create Counter1 element because $Iterable [1] is not a React component. [not-a-component]

     src/App.js
     32│         </div>
     33│       ))}
     34│       <Wrapper render={(count, increment) => {
     35│         return <Counter1 count={count} increment={increment}/>
     36│       }}/>
     37│
     38│       <Wrapper render={(count, increment) => {

     src/components/Counter1.js
 [1]  4│ export const Counter1: React.Node = ({ count, increment }) => {


Error ┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈ src/App.js:35:17

Cannot create Counter1 element because React.Element [1] is not a React component. [not-a-component]

     src/App.js
     32│         </div>
     33│       ))}
     34│       <Wrapper render={(count, increment) => {
     35│         return <Counter1 count={count} increment={increment}/>
     36│       }}/>
     37│
     38│       <Wrapper render={(count, increment) => {

     src/components/Counter1.js
 [1]  4│ export const Counter1: React.Node = ({ count, increment }) => {


Error ┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈ src/App.js:35:17

Cannot create Counter1 element because React.Portal [1] is not a React component. [not-a-component]

     src/App.js
     32│         </div>
     33│       ))}
     34│       <Wrapper render={(count, increment) => {
     35│         return <Counter1 count={count} increment={increment}/>
     36│       }}/>
     37│
     38│       <Wrapper render={(count, increment) => {

     src/components/Counter1.js
 [1]  4│ export const Counter1: React.Node = ({ count, increment }) => {


Error ┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈ src/App.js:35:17

Cannot create Counter1 element because boolean [1] is not a React component. [not-a-component]

     src/App.js
     32│         </div>
     33│       ))}
     34│       <Wrapper render={(count, increment) => {
     35│         return <Counter1 count={count} increment={increment}/>
     36│       }}/>
     37│
     38│       <Wrapper render={(count, increment) => {

     src/components/Counter1.js
 [1]  4│ export const Counter1: React.Node = ({ count, increment }) => {


Error ┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈ src/App.js:35:17

Cannot create Counter1 element because null [1] is not a React component. [not-a-component]

     src/App.js
     32│         </div>
     33│       ))}
     34│       <Wrapper render={(count, increment) => {
     35│         return <Counter1 count={count} increment={increment}/>
     36│       }}/>
     37│
     38│       <Wrapper render={(count, increment) => {

     src/components/Counter1.js
 [1]  4│ export const Counter1: React.Node = ({ count, increment }) => {


Error ┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈ src/App.js:35:17

Cannot create Counter1 element because number [1] is not a React component. [not-a-component]

     src/App.js
     32│         </div>
     33│       ))}
     34│       <Wrapper render={(count, increment) => {
     35│         return <Counter1 count={count} increment={increment}/>
     36│       }}/>
     37│
     38│       <Wrapper render={(count, increment) => {

     src/components/Counter1.js
 [1]  4│ export const Counter1: React.Node = ({ count, increment }) => {


Error ┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈ src/components/Counter1.js:4:37

Cannot assign function to Counter1 because: [incompatible-type]
 • Either inexact function [1] is incompatible with exact object type [2].
 • Or function [1] is incompatible with React.Portal [3].
 • Or property @@iterator is missing in function [1] but exists in $Iterable [4].

     src/components/Counter1.js
      1│ // @flow
      2│ import * as React from 'react';
      3│
 [1]  4│ export const Counter1: React.Node = ({ count, increment }) => {
      5│   return (
      6│     <>
      7│       <div>Counter 1: {count}</div>
      8│       <button onClick={increment}>Increment</button>
      9│     </>
     10│   );
     11│ };
     12│

     /private/tmp/flow/flowlib_1fa18dde633e97c7_501/react.js
 [2] 18│   | React$Element<any>
 [3] 19│   | React$Portal
 [4] 20│   | Iterable<?React$Node>;


Error ┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈ src/components/Counter2.js:4:26

Cannot build a typed interface for this module. You should annotate the exports of this module with types. Missing type
annotation at array pattern: [signature-verification-failure]

     1│ // @flow
     2│ import * as React from 'react';
     3│
     4│ export const Counter2 = ({ count, increment }) => {
     5│   return (
     6│     <>
     7│       <div>Counter 2: {count}</div>


Error ┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈ src/components/Counter2.js:4:47

Cannot build a typed interface for this module. You should annotate the exports of this module with types. Missing type
annotation at function return: [signature-verification-failure]

     1│ // @flow
     2│ import * as React from 'react';
     3│
     4│ export const Counter2 = ({ count, increment }) => {
     5│   return (
     6│     <>
     7│       <div>Counter 2: {count}</div>


Error ┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈ src/components/Wrapper.js:8:28

Cannot build a typed interface for this module. You should annotate the exports of this module with types. Missing type
annotation at array pattern: [signature-verification-failure]

      5│   render: T => React.Node
      6│ };
      7│
      8│ export const Wrapper = <T>({render}): Props<T> => {
      9│   const [count, setCount] = React.useState<number>(0);
     10│
     11│   const increment = (prevCount: number) => setCount(count + 1);


Error ┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈ src/components/Wrapper.js:8:39

Cannot resolve name Props. [cannot-resolve-name]

      5│   render: T => React.Node
      6│ };
      7│
      8│ export const Wrapper = <T>({render}): Props<T> => {
      9│   const [count, setCount] = React.useState<number>(0);
     10│
     11│   const increment = (prevCount: number) => setCount(count + 1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first issue is related to the `Counter1` component line

```
export const Counter1: React.Node = ({ count, increment }) => {
```

Which basically is typing Counter1 as a React.Node, what you really want is a function that RETURNS a React.Node like so

```
export const Counter1 = ({ count, increment }): React.Node => {
```

---

Your second issue related to `Counter2` is related to types-first where every module export has to be explicitly typed so that flow can run at maximum performance, you can read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62192653/13243085).

---

And your last issue in the `Wrapper` component is related to the fact that you have a type called `WrapperProps` but you've used it as `Props` so it's saying it can't find it. Also I believe you've placed your `WrappedProps` in the wrong place, so change it from

```
export const Wrapper = <T>({render}): Props<T> => {
```

to

```
export const Wrapper = <T>({render}: Props<T>): React.Node => {
```

Though in retrospect you might want to think about how a parent component will actually consume this and pass in the generic, because your render func is already expecting two arguments so a generic is not very helpful here. Based on your code, you probably want something like this

```
type WrapperProps = {
  render: (
    number,
    (number) => void,
  ) => React.Node,
};

export const Wrapper = ({render}: WrapperProps): React.Node => {
```

Comment: Thank you! If I wanted to correctly type a functional component with props, how would I do that in flow? For example in TS I can do: const app: React.FC<props> = () => {}; What would be the equivalent in Flow?

Comment: It would be similar to what you've done above, here's a [try](https://flow.org/try/#0JYWwDg9gTgLgBAKjgQwM5wEoFNkGN4BmUEIcA5FDvmQNwBQdMAnmFnAArFjoC8cA3nTgoAXHFQwowAHYBzADR0AvvTq4I0iXADCJMHD4AKQcOSKlYzhG4BKMdjwwAdADkIAEzY8AfAKFxKGABXKGk4Q39hAB53YAA3OAB6b38bZRogA). But Flow runs a lot more on inference than TS might, so you don't need to give the variable a type directly because flow secures soundness by statically analysing your code. Unless you have some code that returns any for some reason then you might have a need to provide a type to gain intellisense and soundness checks

Comment: Also if this answer solves your issue remember to mark is as answered to help others that come along :)